# Styling a list of metadata items fetched with a query and surfaced on Elementor page

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

Wordpress/elementor - I have a custom post which stores details of individuals including what groups they are members of. That data is stored in an ACF checkbox field. I can pull that data into a Wordpress/elementor page using either the  built in dynamic option in several widgets or I can use the post widget and use a custom query stored in function.php. I also tried using [get_field]
Both these methods give a comma seperated list in a single line.
I want to show them as a list or at least each entry on its own line.

I tried to use css to add an unordered list but this just treats the returned values as one list item. The styling options in the widget do not help either. If the returned value is an array is their a way I can split that array into its constituent parts and display each one as a list item?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.